# vuejs textarea 1 value per row

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a problem

I want to get a value for each row value of posts in textarea

i am giving an example
[image]

as in this image
I want to have a value for each line written
When I press the enter key and go to the bottom line and write there, I want to get the text written on that second line as a second value.

my goal is to be able to draw for each column

vuejs compisitions api or option api

Comment: What about just split value from text area? By \n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
<script>
import { ref, computed } from 'vue'

export default {
    setup() {
        const textAreaText = ref('')

        const values = computed(() => textAreaText.value.split('\n'))

        return { textAreaText, values }
    }
}
</script>

<template>
    <textarea v-model="textAreaText"></textarea>

    <p>
        {{ values }}
    </p>
</template>
```

Comment: I think empty lines should be filtered too, still +1